# Export data to XLS (not via CSV) on iOS

Tags: ios, csv, xls

I need to export some data to an .XLS file, pdf, and print.

I already tried the simple solution: exporting it to .CSV with [CHCSVWriter](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser). It works for printing and saving it to pdf (I open the CSV in a UIWebView and [get the PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528658/is-there-any-way-to-generate-pdf-file-from-a-xml-html-template-in-ios) or print from there). However, to use the CSV to be open in excel has two main problems:

1 - First, as the name says, in the CSV the values are separated by commas, and **in some versions** of Excel, it requires the user [to separate 'manually' in cells](http://www.ehow.com/how_2212387_separate-cell-data-excel.html).

2 - I have hebrew characters, and I already tried all the string encodings, and can't have both hebrew and latin characters.

So, after giving up after days of trying to use CSV to solve the issues above, I gave up. How can I export my data to XLS?

Comment: @davedelong might be able to shed some light.

Comment: Hi Natan, finally did you managed to export data to .xls file?

Comment: Hey Yogesh - In the end I think I did that in CSV..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://csharpprogramming.blogspot.it/2010/12/export-datatable-to-excel.html) explains how to programmatically create an Excel (`.xls`) file without using any external library. It just opens a file stream and it writes XML contents straight to it.

It is written in C#, but the core information coming out of it is the XML formatting used to create nodes and fill attributes for corresponding cell values and formatting.

Please consider I have not tried this myself, I found it while doing a search. Please feel free to ask if some C# bits are not clear. HTH

Comment: I worked on this today and I'm starting to have something good. I'll try to build some sort of XLS writer and I'll post here the answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The only problem is that preview in iOS (UIWebView) and Numbers are not able to open this file =( So I am still searching another solution, but it was, no doubt, a good idea.

Comment: Having a look at [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2039521?start=0&tstart=0) and at [this article](http://www.ehow.com/info_12129583_can-iwork-open-xlsx-files.html) it should possible with Numbers 2009. Never ever tried though

Answer (score 3):

The [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) library provides this functionality for both `xls` and `xlsx` formats. There is no iOS version, but [people say](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10270108/730701) the iOS version is coming. You may want to [contact LibXL support](http://www.libxl.com/contact.html) to confirm this.

EDIT:
The iOS version is available now.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. Any other possible approach?

Comment: @NatanR. I would recommend using `xlsx` format, if possible. It can be open with older Excel versions with add-on installed. It's an open, xml based format and the files are smaller compared to `xls`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @Adam. But I still need to know how to do it =(

Comment: I have succesfully created the .xls (xml based), and it can be opened normally in excel. But it doesn't open in a UIWebView or in Numbers. Do you have any idea why? Trying to save as .xlsx doesn't solves the problem...